# No email also not pushed to analytics

Tags: orders, order-email, google-analytics

We have a site where sometimes when an order is made, it isn't pushed to google analytics (we're using the google api and the store id etc is correct as some orders get pushed)

The only thing I notice is that the orders that aren't pushed to analytics also have no order email sent but I have absolutely no idea what would cause this.

**I've looked at:**

payment method

store view used

time of day (maybe cron?)

status

customer group,

customer sign up date

guest or customer (can't be the issue as we don't allow guest checkout).

The issue happens on a variation of all of these parameters - there isn't anything connecting the orders that aren't pushed into analytics, apart from the fact the order emails aren't sent and I can't understand why they wouldn't be sent, I've put in test orders and used non existent emails, emails that are spelt wrong (that couldn't exist) etc etc and for ME the order email is ALWAYS sent.

Is there any reason some order emails won't send and would this affect analytics?

Comment: What are the payment gateways that you're using? Are you redirected offsite?

Comment: paypal and pro forma are the two payment methods, I'm not sure if the issue happens on paypal but I ruled out payment method as it sometimes happens on pro forma and sometimes not so it can't be caused by pro forma? I can't find any orders where the issue has occured via paypal but that doesn't mean it doesn't happen via paypal.

Comment: It could be two things. If the customer is taken offsite to complete the payment method, they may not be coming back to the success page. Alternatively the customer may have JavaScript tracking turned off which can block analytics. You could try something like https://www.hotjar.com/ to track the sessions and see what they're doing.

Comment: but would javascript tracking being turned off block the email as well? I was under the impression the email was queued as part of the php that ran when an order was submitted

Comment: also you can't get anywhere with javascript disabled, the site gives you an error telling you off for trying to use an e-commerce site without javascript on

Comment: JS wouldn't affect the email no. Are the orders that haven't been tracked set to the correct status? Do you have any sort of 'pending payment' status?

Comment: They're of a varying status, some are completed, some are pending, some are on hold etc etc etc. Just normal order behaviour